# Does Mercy's revive restore ammo and ability cooldowns?

Tags: overwatch

Mercy's revive restores all downed teammates within a short range to full health. This much is obvious. However, suppose you're reviving a Zarya who died with 0 ammo and full cooldown on both of her abilities. Will that Zarya be revived with ammo and bubbles available, or will she have to reload and wait out the remainder of her cooldowns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By watching [this video](https://youtu.be/mwp-23UBIZM?t=20), I can say that Mercy's ultimate restores health and ammo but usually not cooldowns.

Comment: +1, at 0:22 he is revived with a few seconds left on the Wraith Form cooldown. Also, he had 0 ammo left in the clip when killed, and it is filled as he is revived.

Comment: There is a claim that D.Va's Call Mech (human form "ultimate") gauge actually fills up to 100% upon resurrection. If there is an evidence, then I would like to edit the answer and add it.

Comment: @ArleCamille I'm playing D.Va quite often and got resurrected by a Mercy more than once.... And you don't respawn with your mech ready if it was not charged before dying, that would be way too easy

Comment: In my experience, ammo does *not* refill. If the Reaper had 0 ammo left in his clip when he died, then it's more likely that his reload animation started, then got cancelled by death- you can do similar by hitting reload then wraith forming, you come back with full ammo. A few times when I've been ressed as a Junkrat, I still only have 2-3 grenades left in the clip.

Comment: @Sidewinder94 I have editted the answer with a new video where D.Va died right after using her ultimate, and revived without her mech but with her ultimate ready to use.

Comment: @Darakath Requires additional verification. *Self-destruct* fills up the *Call Mech* gauge upon the robot's detonation, so it is irrelevant with *Resurrect*.

Comment: @ArleCamille Ah, I'll try to find a better example.

Comment: @ArleCamille This forum post seems to suggest that you don't revive with your ultimate ready. http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20745286270

Comment: I've been revived as D.Va outside of her mech and I still had to work for Summon Mech again, so I don't think the second claim is true.

Comment: @GarrettJ I have removed it due to the lack of proof.